# Creating a man page in Minix 3?

Tags: manpage, minix

I'm unsure on how to go about creating a new man page in the Minix 3. Groff and troff aren't available in Minix, and after researching I can't find any alternative. How do I go about creating a new man page in Minix?

Answer (score 1):

Minix3 has [`mandoc`](http://mdocml.bsd.lv/) (aka [`mdocml`](http://mdocml.bsd.lv/)) in [its tree](http://git.minix3.org/index.cgi?p=minix.git;a=tree;f=external/bsd/mdocml) which supports both [`mdoc(7)`](http://mdocml.bsd.lv/man/mdoc.7.html) and the legacy [`man(7)`](http://mdocml.bsd.lv/man/man.7.html).

The [`mandoc(1)`](http://mdocml.bsd.lv/man/mandoc.1.html) utility, by default, writes the formatted text to the standard output, and the `-a` option causes it pipe the output to a pager "just like `man(1)` would".

```
mandoc -a path/to/myprog.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'm able to create a man page and display it using "man ./prog.1". Do you know how to "install" my man page so that it can be called simply with "man prog"?

Comment: Use `install(1)` to install the man-page to a directory searched for by `man(1)`.  The defaults are specified in [`/etc/man.conf`](http://git.minix3.org/index.cgi?p=minix.git;a=blob;f=etc/man.conf#l45), and a local directory can be easily added my modifying the `MANPATH` environment variable.  ex. `install -c -m 444 proc.1 /usr/local/man/man1`